# asp.net mvc How to display default value on a date type textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, default-value, html.textbox

I'm developing in asp.net mvc.
I want to have a textbox which is date type, so there's a shortcut that user can click and select a date instead of type in. Meanwhile I want the textbox to display a default date value.

I have tried 2 ways:
`<input type="date" name="toDate" value="@DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString()" />`

`@Html.TextBox("date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new { type = "date"})`

But these two methods generate textbox with 'dd/mm/yyyy' displaying in the box instead of the the default value I set. When I right click on the textbox and inspect element, I can see that there is a value of current date, but it can't show in the textbox!

When I replace the `type="date"` to `type="text"`, I can see the default value on textbox. But there's no shortcut for me to select a date, it only allows me to type in.

How do I do this to reserve both the shortcut and default value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want HTML5 date picker. It depends on web browser you are using. Currently, Google chrome and Opera support that.

```
<input type="date" value="2012-10-10"/>
@Html.TextBox("date", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), new { type = "date" })
```

Comment: The first one <input type="date" value="2012-10-10"/> is working. But it can't dynamically display the current date. When I try to replace it with a parameter, eg: var x = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()       <input type="date" value="@x"/>, it doesn't work again. The second line of your code returns the same result as mine

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do

```
@Html.TextBox("date", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"), new { type = "date"})
```

Comment: a date type textbox which I can select date by click the shortcut, but the default value is dd/mm/yyyy. It doesn't show the real date

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this:
<input type="date" name="FechIni" value="@DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />